# How to calculate Hilbert polynomial

Tags: algebraic-geometry, computer-algebra-systems

Consider the ideal $I=\langle x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2,x_0x_1+x_2x_3\rangle \subseteq k[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3]$ for $k=\mathbb{F}_{32749}$. I am trying to calculate the dimension of the ***projective*** variety generated by this ideal.

Following the book *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms*, I first note that the generators $x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2$ and $x_0x_1+x_2x_3$ are a Gröbner basis for $I$. Thus, $\langle LT(I)\rangle =\langle x_0^2,x_0x_1\rangle$ using Lex order with $x_0>x_1>x_2>x_3$.

Then I count the number of monomials of degree $s$ not in $\langle LT(I) \rangle$ to get the Hilbert function.

The number of monomials of degree $s$ in $4$ variables is $\binom{s+3}{s}$.

The monomials of degree $s$ in $\langle LT(I) \rangle$ have the form,
$$x_0^2f$$
or
$$x_0x_1g$$
where $f,g$ have degree $s-2$. The number of monomials of degree $s-2$ is $\binom{s+1}{s-2}$.

There is double counting if we subtract this number twice, so we have to count the overlap, that is when,
$$x_0^2f=x_0x_1g,$$
in other words,
$$f=x_1\alpha$$
and
$$g=x_0\alpha$$
for some monomial of degree $s-3$, $\alpha$. The number of monomials of degree $s-3$ is $\binom{s}{s-3}$. Hence, the Hilbert function is,
$$HF=\binom{s+3}{s}-2\binom{s+1}{s-2}+\binom{s}{s-3}=\frac{s^2+5s+2}{2}$$
which is the Hilbert Polynomial for large enough $s$.

When using Macaulay2, I get the the Hilbert polynomial is,
$$HP(s)=4s.$$

**Where am I going wrong?**

Comment: I can't help you with the Grobner basis parts, but what you have here is an intersection of two smooth conics in $\Bbb P^3$ which don't share any common component. Therefore you get a variety of dimension 1 and degree 4, which is exactly what Macaulay2 is telling you.

Comment: Right, just want to know where my own calculations are going wrong so I can understand the behind the scenes of Macaulay2.

Comment: As a note, the assumption that $x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2,x_0x_1+x_2x_3$ is a Groebner basis is wrong